# generate weekly shift with two days off contraints

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, random

I want to randomly generate a 8 hours shift for worker.

Start from 0 to 24*7+8(next monday's 8am). Each day has a start time and end time.

(0,0) if off.

the output should look like this:

```
[[  0   0]
 [ 29  37]
 [ 60  68]
 [ 80  88]
 [  0   0]
 [121 129]
 [165 173]]
```

Shift can be overnight: eg, 23--31 for 1st day.

There must be a 12 hours gap between shifts. from example above: if the 2nd day is not off, then 2nd day shift starts from 32.

if 3rd day off, end time of 2nd will be 48-1. so wiggle room for 2nd is [32,47]

This is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np

LastShiftEndTime = 24*7 +8 # 176 next monday's morning 8am
hours_168 =168
day_rest=12
days = np.arange(7)
time_8h=8
off_days_8h=2
off_days_8h_parttime=5


def shift8h():
    shift = np.zeros((7, shift_start_end), dtype=int)
    twodaysoff = np.sort(np.random.choice(range(7), off_days_8h, replace=False)) # random 2 dif number
    # twodaysoff=[0,3] # twodaysoff=[1,6] # wodaysoff=[0,1]
    # twodaysoff=[3,6]
    # print("twodaysoff:", twodaysoff)
    work_days = np.setdiff1d(days, twodaysoff) # 5 work days

    for i in work_days:
        for j in twodaysoff:
            if j - i != 1: # if the day is NOT the previous day before the off-days
                starttime1 = np.random.randint(0, 23) + i * 24
                endtime = starttime1 + time_8h
                shift[i] = (starttime1, endtime)
                # else:
            if j - i == 1 and j != 6: # if the days is the day before the off-days
                starttime1 = np.random.randint(0, 16) + i * 24 #not start work withing 8 hours before midnight of off
                endtime = starttime1 + time_8h
                shift[i] = (starttime1, endtime)
                # add
                if starttime1 - shift[i - 1][1] < 12:  # 12 hours break btw work days
                    # print('yes')
                    # shift[i-1][0]=np.random.randint(0,starttime1-12) +i*24
                    shift[i - 1][0] = np.random.randint(0, 10) + i * 24
                    # print(shift[i-1][0])
                    shift[i - 1][1] = shift[i - 1][0] + time_8h

                    # print(shift[i])
            if j == 6:
                shift[j] = [0, 0]
            if j == 1:
                shift[j - 1][0] = (np.random.randint(0, 17))  # 0..16 24-8
                shift[j - 1][1] = shift[j - 1][0] + time_8h
    return shift


def modify_shift8h():
    mod_shift8h = shift8h()
    # mod_shift8h = test
    #print("old:", a)
    for i in range(1, len(mod_shift8h) - 1):
        if abs(mod_shift8h[i][0] - mod_shift8h[i - 1][1]) < 12 and np.array_equal(mod_shift8h[i],
                                                    np.array([0, 0])) == False:  # and mod_shift8h[i][0]-a[i-1][1]!=0:
            mod_shift8h[i - 1][1] = mod_shift8h[i][0] - 12 - np.random.randint(0, 4)
            mod_shift8h[i - 1][0] = mod_shift8h[i - 1][1] - time_8h
    return mod_shift8h
```

It does not work on twodaysoff=[0,4] and twodaysoff=[0,3]

### ---- Revised Benjamin's code.

```
import numpy as np
def sxx():
# Position days off
    work = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0], np.bool)
    np.random.shuffle(work)

    # Pick start time for the first day
    start = np.zeros(7, np.int16)
    first_day = np.argmax(work)
    start[first_day] = np.random.randint(first_day*24, (first_day+1)*24)

    # Pick start times for the following days
    for i in range(1,7):
        if work[i] == True:
            while (start[i] - start[i-1]) < 12 + 8:
                start[i] = np.random.randint(i*24, (i+1)*24-1)
            if i ==6 :
                start[i] = np.random.randint(i*24,(i+1)*24)
                if work[i] and (start[i] - start[i - 1]) < 12 + 8:
                    # print(start[i-1])
                    start[i-1] = np.random.randint ((i-1)*24,(i-1)*24 +(24-8))
                    start[i] = np.random.randint(start[i-1]+20, (i+1)*24)

    # End times
    end = start + 8
    end[~work] = 0
    # return list(zip(start, end))
    return np.array(list(zip(start, end)))
```

This is almost correct, except return

```
[[ 21  29]
 [ 44  52]
 [  0   0]
 [ 87  95]
 [  0   0]
 [128 136]
 [157 165]]
```

here 52 is not right.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework.

Comment: @David it is not homework though...

Answer (score 0):

That is very complicated code...

Start by selecting which days are off, then pick the start time for the first day. Next, generate start times for the next day until they match your 12 hour criteria. End times are 8 hours from the start times.

```
import numpy

# Position days off
work = numpy.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0], numpy.bool)
numpy.random.shuffle(work)

# Pick start time for the first day
start = numpy.zeros(7, numpy.int16)
first_day = numpy.argmax(work)
start[first_day] = numpy.random.randint(first_day*24, (first_day+1)*24)

# Pick start times for the following days
for i in range(1,7):
    if work[i]:
        while (start[i] - start[i-1]) < 12 + 8:
            start[i] = numpy.random.randint(i*24, (i+1)*24+9)

# End times
end = start + 8
end[~work] = 0

print zip(start, end)
>>> [(0, 0), (45, 53), (0, 0), (74, 82), (118, 126), (141, 149), (168, 176)]
```

Something like that... although there likely is a simpler way to do it, using pure Python. Writing out the time ranges, constraints, etc. on paper will help you figure out if this answer is correct or not for yourself.

Comment: thanks for the input. I fixed code as well. Yours: [(7, 15), (46, 54), (69, 77), (0, 0), (0, 0), (151, 159), (175, 183)].  I expect the last day ends before  24*7+8

Comment: and [(0, 0), (22, 30), (74, 82), (103, 111), (124, 132), (0, 0), (167, 175)]
This 22 is  not correct. 2nd start at 24. @Benjamin

Comment: @EskimoT: fixed the second issue, will leave it up to you or someone else to fix the first. I've offered a general example of how to approach this more concisely; I didn't mean this to be a completely validated read-for-use code...

Comment: If you edit your post to show what you have tried, I can comment further. It's not a matter of luck...

Comment: Please take a look at it. Thanks!